# Twoway view spannable grid layout parameters not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using the twoway view for the first and i'm struggling to specify the layout attributes for the views. I have tow kinds of views, header and the episode.

This is the xml of both:
Show:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_16dp"
android:layout_width="248dp"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:background="@color/black">

 //More views...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="54dp"
android:background="@color/red_800">
//More views
```

I set the height to be 54dp in the header and 160dp for the show but what i'm getting is this, it's always the same (wrong) height, the red bar is the header.

http://postimg.org/image/xx1dk45n9/

Code:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView title,date,rate,episode;
    public ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        rate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        episode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.episode);
    }

}

    public static class ViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView date,children;

    public ViewHolderHeader(View view) {
        super(view);
        date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        children = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.children);
    }

}

public CalendarAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    readDateFormat(context);
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern, Locale.US);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view;
    if (viewType == CalendarGridItem.TYPE.SHOW.ordinal()){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.calendar_grid_tile, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.calendar_grid_header, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderHeader(view);
    }
}


  @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final View view = holder.itemView;
    final CalendarGridItem item = mShows.get(position);
    final SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp =
            (SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

    if (getItemViewType(position) == CalendarGridItem.TYPE.HEADER.ordinal()){ //Header

        final ViewHolderHeader holder1 = (ViewHolderHeader)holder;

        CalendarHeader header = (CalendarHeader)item;

        Log.d(TAG,"Entrou header: "+header.getDate());

        //Mete a colSpan a 2
        if (lp.colSpan != 2)
            lp.colSpan = 2;

        lp.height = 100; //Even forcing the height doesn't work
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    }else{ //Show

        final ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder)holder;
        UpcomingShow show = (UpcomingShow)item;

        if (lp.colSpan != 1)
            lp.colSpan = 1;

        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    }

}
```

Fragment layout:

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/spanGrid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
style="@style/TwoWayView"
app:twowayview_layoutManager="SpannableGridLayoutManager"
app:twowayview_numColumns="2"/>
```

What i'm doing wrong ? I'm not used to the recycler view way of doing things, i must be missing something. Teste with Android 4.1.1 and 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Currently have quite the same problem (mine is that elements are all "squares")
It seems like it not possible to give specific height/width for elements in the item layout.

When you look in the source code, in the SpannableGridLayoutManager.java file, you have the method : LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp).
In there, those are the incrimated lines :

```
final LayoutParams spannableLp = new LayoutParams((MarginLayoutParams) lp);
spannableLp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
spannableLp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

But if you do remove that, you "break" all the logic for the spannable grid view...

Answer (score 0):

I also thought that `TwoWayView` can display the items as squares. So I was digging in the  source and found , like Wicha said, that MATCH_PARENT in two places was causing the undesired behaviour.

So I made the following adjustments in the `SpannableGridLayoutManager` file (commented some lines in `checkLayoutParams` method) :

```
 @Override
    public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
//        if (lp.width != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ||
//            lp.height != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
//            return false;
//        }

        if (lp instanceof LayoutParams) {
        (.....)
    }
```

and here (use width and height from layout params in `generateLayoutParams` method) :

```
 @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
        final LayoutParams spannableLp = new LayoutParams((MarginLayoutParams) lp);
        spannableLp.width = lp.width; //LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        spannableLp.height = lp.height; //LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        if (lp instanceof LayoutParams) {
        (....)
    }
```

Also, in your Adapter class, goes something like this :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        viewHolder.image.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = ((SpannableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams());
        layoutParams.width = cell_width * item.size; //multiply size
        layoutParams.height = cell_height * item.size;//multiply size
        layoutParams.colSpan = item.size;
        layoutParams.rowSpan = item.size;
        viewHolder.image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Some observations:

- cell_width is calculated like screen width/3 in portrait orientation and screen width/4 in landscape.
- cell_height is calculated like image_width / image_ratio.
- item.size : I decided to have 1:1 or 2:2 or 3:3 aspect ratios for the items, so item_size is the multiplication value.